# Is it possible for a ClickOnce application to interact with a web page

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, data-transfer

My application, written in VB.Net 4.5 and deployed using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), gets information through parameters when it is opened via the link on a website. The application uses that information to modify data collected from hardware connected to a virtual serial port. The data is usually on the order of a 3-15 kilobytes of plain text. The data then needs to return to the page (in a text box), and the page submitted, at which point the application closes.

Previously, the page used a Java applet, but increased Java security has made upkeep very time consuming.

Is it possible for the application to send data back to the same web page, still open in the browser, and submit that page?

If not, what would the simplest way for the application to send its data to the webserver, knowing that it needs user credentials (and a few other pieces of data) to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a post to the webpage from your application. See the WebRequest object